# bootstrap remove upward arrow in dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter bootstap and wish to remove the upward arrow on the dropdown-menu whis is in my nav. I cannot find a reference in the bootstrap.css.

[image: Bootstrap]

```
.navbar .dropdown-menu:after {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 border-left: 6px solid transparent;
 border-right: 6px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 6px solid #000; /* change color here, modified for a black arrow */
 position: absolute;
 top: -6px;
 left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I cannot find a reference to the markup you have in the question.

Comment: I have added what I can find in the bootstrap.css

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would not recommend you to edit the `bootstrap.css` file. You can overwrite the styling in your custom stylesheet to hide the arrow for that component like this:

```
.dropdown-menu:after {
    border: none !important;
    content: "" !important;
}
```

With this method you can even do the overwriting for a specific dropdown only. For example, if your dropdown was a child of an element with the id `my_dropdown`, you could do:

```
#my_dropdown .dropdown-menu:after {
    border: none !important;
    content: "" !important;
}
```

This would allow you to have an arrow for other dropdowns, while hiding it for this specific dropdown.

Comment: sorry this not get rid of the upward arrow

Comment: yet the white arrow is gone but there seems to be a dark version still remaining with half opacity

Comment: I had to do this also, thanks .navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before {
  border-bottom: none;
}

Answer (score 13):

The following css worked for me:

```
.dropdown-menu:before, 
.dropdown-menu:after {
     border: none !important;
     content: none !important;
}
```

If you remove any of the two selectors, some detail from the arrow would still remain - either a gray or a white triangle.

(Just decided to add this in case someone is looking for an answer later, as the accepted answer didn't work for me.)

Answer (score 3):

You can also do:

```
.dropdown-menu:before,
.dropdown-menu:after {
  display:none;
}
```

This will disable the arrow and its shadow.