# bootstrap 3 arrow on dropdown menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap 2 the dropdown menu had an upwards arrow as it can be seen [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#dropdowns)
(i am not talking about the carret). Now using bootstrap 3 or latest git this arrow doesn't exist in my simple example bellow nor in the [examples](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) on the bootstrap homepage.

How can I add this arrow again using bootstrap 3?

```
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Menu
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

PS:To be precise the picture can be seen in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792132/bootstrap-remove-upward-arrow-in-dropdown) stackoverflow article.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You need to add :after and :before css rules to your `dropdown-menu`.  These rules are taken from Bootstrap 2, and are what draw the triangle above the dropdown.

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kq5Ef/)

```
.dropdown-menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
}

.dropdown-menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}
```

Confused how? [See here for an animation that explains css triangles](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lotjh)

Comment: This isn't responsive though, i.e. the placement of the arrow is incorrect.

Comment: What is the need for both `:before` and `:after`?  It appears to work with just one of the two.  http://jsfiddle.net/kq5Ef/387/

Comment: @im1dermike Looks like your fiddle has both... but to answer your question: `:before` creates a gray (#ccc) triangle, and `:after` creates a white triangle. The gray one is placed behind to create the border around the white triangle.

Comment: You should wrap the code with `@media (min-width: 768px) {}` to make sure the arrow doesn't appear in mobile navbar.

Comment: Works! But how to place arrow at middle?

Comment: @AlexanderMistakidis any idea how we can make the arrow larger? similar to this [example](https://twentysixteendemo.wordpress.com/style-guide/) ?

Comment: @RainMan simply increase the size of the border and reposition top/left as needed

Comment: @AlexanderMistakidis thanks for comment, that is what I tried but I can't get the triangle image aligned. I increased everything by 3px

Answer (score 18):

Just to follow up on this - if you want the arrow to position itself correctly (like when using it on a navbar element that is right-aligned, you need the following additional CSS to ensure the arrow is right-aligned:

```css
.navbar .navbar-right > li > .dropdown-menu:before,
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu.navbar-right:before {
    right: 12px; left: auto;
}

.navbar .navbar-right > li > .dropdown-menu:after,
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu.navbar-right:after {
    right: 13px; left: auto;
}
```

Note the "navbar-right" - that was introduced in BS3 instead of pull-right for navbars.

Answer (score 3):

The CSS that Alexander Mistakidis provided is correct.  Which is to say, it creates the arrow atop the dropdown menu in Bootstrap.  In order to position it correctly in a responsive view (@user2993108), you can change the `left` attribute for each of the class selectors (`.dropdown-menu:before`,`.dropdown-menu:after`) at different media queries or breakpoints.

For example...

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {

.dropdown-menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 30px; /* change for positioning */
  ...
}

.dropdown-menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 31px; /* change for positioning */
  ...
}

}

@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 401px) {

.dropdown-menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 38px; /* change for positioning */
  ...
}

.dropdown-menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 39px; /* change for positioning */
  ...
}

}
```

and so on...

Answer (score 2):

This builds on the work by Alexander Mistakidis and Joyrex to support optional arrows and dropup menus. In my case I did not want to have an arrow on *all* of the dropdown menus, only some.

With this, you add the `arrow` class to the `dropdown-menu` element to get the arrow. If Bootstrap is positioning the dropdown/dropup to the left, also add `arrow-right` to shift the arrow to the other side.

```
// add an arrow to the dropdown menus
.dropdown-menu.arrow:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}
.dropdown-menu.arrow:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}

// postion at the top for a 'down' menu
.dropdown .dropdown-menu.arrow:before {
  top: -7px;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu.arrow:after {
  top: -6px;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
}

// postion at the bottom for an 'up' menu
.dropup .dropdown-menu.arrow:before {
  bottom: -7px;
  border-top: 7px solid #ccc;
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropup .dropdown-menu.arrow:after {
  bottom: -6px;
  border-top: 6px solid #ffffff;
}

// support to move the arrow to the right-hand-side
.dropdown-menu.arrow.arrow-right:before,
.dropup .dropdown-menu.arrow.arrow-right:before {
  right: 15px;
  left: auto;
}
.dropdown-menu.arrow.arrow-right:after,
.dropup .dropdown-menu.arrow.arrow-right:after {
  right: 16px;
  left: auto;
}
```