# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - Add Arrow on Dropdown Menu for Desktop Only

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navigation, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I used this method to add my arrow: [bootstrap 3 arrow on dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983995/bootstrap-3-arrow-on-dropdown-menu)

Works great on desktop, but the only problem is the arrow still appears in the mobile view when it collapses (<768px).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nolabel/Mk9PD/

```
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu, ul.dropdown-menu {
    border: 5px solid #7ed1e3;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.dropdown-menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  left: 24%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 11px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 11px solid #7ed1e3;
  border-left: 11px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}
.dropdown-menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
  left: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 12px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 12px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
}
```

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: What should happen with the content in the dropdowns? Should they still be there and should just the arrows disappear?

Comment: sebastian_oe, it should show like it normally show. Juan C. got a pretty good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could put your `:before` and `:after` inside of a media query with the  device [width](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) that you wish to be shown only

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdragon/Mk9PD/12/)**

```
@media screen and (min-width:750px) {
    .dropdown-menu:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: -16px;
        left: 24%;
        display: inline-block;
        border-right: 11px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 11px solid #7ed1e3;
        border-left: 11px solid transparent;
        content:'';
    }
    .dropdown-menu:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: -17px;
        left: 25%;
        display: inline-block;
        border-right: 12px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 12px solid #ccc;
        border-left: 12px solid transparent;
        border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        content:'';
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you got a vote down, but this solution works! I was trying to use the responsive utility classes, but that has been very unsuccessful.

Comment: Juan, it is more correct to use min-width:768px as opposed to 750px b/c the nav collapses @767px.