# How to replace arrow dropdown select in boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to remove the default Bootstrap arrow and insert a new image in its place.  I was successful in removing the arrow, but I have 2 other problems.

I don't know:

- how to insert a new image in the select tag.
- why the css below does not remove the arrow in ie11?

My code can be found here:
my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n4Lob0t1/

html:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="DevelopmentTool">Development Tool</label>
          <form >
            <select class="form-control">
              <option></option>
            </select>
          </form>
</div>
```

css:

```
   select.form-control {
   -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
 }
```

Comment: thanks but my question refer 2 things not just one. :)

Comment: While the duplicate has solution for second question, new image is not covered there.

Comment: Ask one question per question

Comment: @Raduken Next time, please one question per post.

Comment: thanks all resolved my problem.

Comment: Marking this as a dupe as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it like this:

```
.styleSelect select {
  background: transparent;
  width: 168px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 34px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: #000;
}

.styleSelect {
  width: 140px;
  height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url("images/downArrow.png") no-repeat right #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Here:
[Change color and appearance of drop down arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611482/change-color-and-appearance-of-drop-down-arrow)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to have a look at the `.form-group` background attribute.

See more on this post [select arrow style change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218307/select-arrow-style-change)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for IE 10/11. prob not IE 8/9

```
`select::-ms-expand{display:none;}`
```

for the arrow this is just one answer but there are a lot of question on stack that ask this.
[bootstrap 3 arrow on dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983995/bootstrap-3-arrow-on-dropdown-menu)